# Cant Import mysql system DB from another server

Tags: mysql, restore, windows, import, windows-server

Both Servers are the same in hardware, OS, and MySQL versions (5.6.11).

One server has MySQL on it and on the other one I just setup a fresh instance.

I want to import all of the data to the second server.

I dump the mysql DB to a .sql file and when I try to import it on the other server I initially get no errors. At that point if I stop the mysql service it won't start up again and I get this error logged in event viewer:

```
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

So it looks like the import is not working. Is there another command I have to run after importing the mysql database?

Comment: How are you importing the dumped file?

Comment: The first thing to check would be if the error is correct- does the mysql.user table exist? Go to your `datadir` and check for a couple of files named `$datadir\mysql\user.{frm,MYD}` your import script may be deleting the table and not recreating it.